# Query conditional unique cases for Google Sheet Mailing List

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

For maintaining a research project I'm setting up a Google Sheet to create mailing lists using logical operators.

The basic structure is a "contacts" sheet with an ever-growing list of email addresses, names, etc. I then add a new sheet for each new email-campaign (i.e., a mass email to be sent out). There is also an "unsubscribe" list to suppress email address inclusion in any future campaigns.

I struggle to come up with a solution that allows me to identify email addresses that have been e.g.,

- (a) never contacted as yet
- (b) twice contacted already
- (c) not contacted through "campaign1"
- AND are not part of "unsubscribe"

My logical approach has been to establish a "history" sheet that lists all email addresses of any campaigns so far. I'm challenged to find a solution that compares "contacts" and "history" and correctly returns the rows that align with my search parameters, yet returns a given email address no more than once (so as to not email people multiple times per campaign).

I've tried to various configurations and nesting of `QUERY`, `FILTER`, `SORTN` including `UNIQUE` to establish a universal approach that uses "contacts" as a central source from which to logically extract rows as illustrated above.

This sheet reflects the above (no functions) and invites for suggestions: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NRY-udwepbFahVryX7FF6WIQ0vtFJkjuuhRWFJVAWnI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. never contacted as yet

```
=FILTER(contacts!A2:D1000, NOT(COUNTIF(contacts!B2:B1000, history!B2:B1000)))
```

[image: 0]

### 2. twice contacted already

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(history!A2:D1000, COUNTIF(history!B2:B1000, history!B2:B1000)>1))
```

[image]

### 3. not contacted through "campaign1"

```
=FILTER(campaign2!A2:D1000, NOT(COUNTIF(campaign1!B2:B1000, campaign2!B2:B1000)))
```

[image: 0]

### 4. are not part of "unsubscribe"

```
=FILTER(contacts!A2:D1000, NOT(COUNTIF(unsubscribe!A1:A999, contacts!B2:B1000)))
```

[image: 0]

### 5. twice contacted already AND are not part of "unsubscribe"

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(history!A2:D1000, COUNTIF(history!B2:B1000, history!B2:B1000)>1, 
 NOT(COUNTIF(unsubscribe!A1:A999, history!B2:B1000))))
```

[image: 2]

### 6. define the formulas using named ranges.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(History, COUNTIF(historyB, historyB)>1, 
 NOT(COUNTIF(unsubscribe, historyB))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Many thanks! I now wonder two questions that I could not work out, please: (1) how to nest filters e.g. twice contacted already AND are not part of "unsubscribe", (2) define the formulas using named ranges. Some examples are highly appreciated.